# unable to init nuxt 3 npx showing " ERROR Failed to download template from registry: fetch failed"

Tags: nuxt3

I have fixed it by just updating DNS in windows, it might also fix on ubuntu.

1. [image]

[image]

Just add preferred **8.8.8.8** and Alternate DNS will be 8.8.4.4

Restart CMD and try again, make sure to restart all open CMD

One Additional help here to starting Nuxt Project

https://nuxt.new/